# Isolated Storage for UWP

Tags: win-universal-app

May I ask about how to store the temporary data and read temporary data from Isolated storage and Isolated storage support for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App Development?
Thank You.

Comment: copy your title and paste it to google or bing and see many answers you want, please do a little search before you post in here

Comment: @MasihAkbari I had do research before I ask.

Answer (score 6):

Isolated storage used in WP silverlight . 
If you want a temporary folder to store you can use `ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder`
If you want a Folder to store application data for a long time and you need them you can use `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`
If you want your app to have a sync between devices , it means you want to have same data on different devices you have to use RoamingFolder instead of LocalFolder . RoamingFolder share application data between devices and help you to make a more universal app .

Answer (score 2):

Use the ApplicationData class to get a StorageFolder instance for the temp folder:

```
var tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
```

You can then use the StorageFolder to create a file in the temp folder:

```
var tempFile = await tempFolder.CreateFileAsync("TempFileName.tmp", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

Or use it to open an existing file:

```
var tempFile = await tempFolder.GetFileAsync("TempFileName.tmp");
```