# UWP read temporary files and documentation

Tags: c#, uwp, documentation

I have tried to use the windows app documentation to read temporary files (read and write) on UWP. But I couldn't make it work using the documentation as in the example at this link below

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data)
in this parte:

```
async void WriteTimestamp()
{
  Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter formatter = 
   new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("longtime");

StorageFile sampleFile = await temporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("dataFile.txt", 
   CreateCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(sampleFile, formatter.Format(DateTimeOffset.Now));
}
```

But soon I have a problem with "temporaryFolder". It's says doesn't exist in the current context. So...
I try: (1) add "using Windows.Storage;" don't work...
(2) declare outside:

```
public Windows.Storage.StorageFolder temporaryFolder { get; set; }
```

this time the code says there is no error, but when I start the program it stops. **" 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
App12UIWindows.Page2.temporaryFolder.get return null."**

So I tried a solution from here (stackoverflow) and it worked. Link:
[Alternative Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666575/isolated-storage-for-uwp/34242711)

My question is: why it go wrong? the documentation is correct or is it something else?
or am I searching in the wrong place? My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Windows.Storage;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace App12UIWindows
{
/// <summary>

/// </summary>
public sealed partial class Page2 : Page
{
    public Page2()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        SaveTempFunc();
        readMyFileTemp();
    }

    public Windows.Storage.StorageFolder temporaryFolder { get; set; }
    

    async void SaveTempFunc()
    {


        StorageFile salvandoClientesT = await 
        temporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("textOf_Information.txt") ;
        await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(salvandoClientesT,"test .. just like that... and 
        anothers words to a file");


    }
    //Fim salvando memória temporária

    //Lendo na memória temporária arquivo de texto
    async void readMyFileTemp()
    {
        try
        {
            StorageFile lendoTextoSalvo = await 
            temporaryFolder.GetFileAsync("textOf_Information.txt");
            String timestamp = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(lendoTextoSalvo);
           

         }
        catch (Exception)
         {

         }

       }


    }



 }
```

**Sorry for the bad english :)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' App12UIWindows.Page2.temporaryFolder.get return null."

The problem is that you just declare `temporaryFolder`, but have not apply reference to `temporaryFolder`. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data#retrieve-the-temporary-data-container) mentioned above. pass `ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder` to  temporaryFolder variable.

```
public Windows.Storage.StorageFolder temporaryFolder { get; set; } = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
```

Comment: Thanks! this works! And a edit the line "temporaryFolder.CreateFileAsync("textoComClientes.txt", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting) ;" to exit a exception chatch. I'm going to study the code and links placed here. Thank you again. Documentation still difficult for me to understand. :)